# how to get current row number or cell index in laravel excel maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

Now I'm trying to find how to get current row number or cell id in [laravel excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) but i cannot find it , i need to get the current row number or cell id because i need to produce some error message that mentioning the current row number or cell id.

[image: excel_file_image] ,

please open the excel image link to see the image
okay for example ,based on the image  i want to know the current active cell and for example active cell is at column B and row 2 , how do i get that cell index or row number ?

```
$sheet = 'public/site.xls';

        // load excel content
        $excel = Excel::load($sheet, function ($reader)
        {
            $results = $reader->toObject();

            foreach($results as $result)
            {

               // i want to know how to retrieve active cell index here

            }

        });
```

Note: i don't want the value of the cell but i want index of the cell

Comment: In view: `@foreach($something as $index => $item) {{ $index }} @endforaech` what's wrong with that? Please post some code examples to give us an idea how you're trying to do this.

Comment: @devk check it , i already update the description to more detail

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I wanted the user to specify the column number containing phone numbers when uploading an excel file.
I therefore need to find the column by index number input by user.

In your situation and mine, we both need the row and column indexes.
Here is how I hacked it.
  [image]

```
//Array to hold the phone numbers
$phone_numbers = array();

//Load Excel file as array
$rows = Excel::load($contacts_file)->toArray();

//Loop through each row
foreach($rows as $row_index=>$row){ //$row_index is the row index
    $col_headers = array_keys($row); //Gives you an array, in my case ["serial","contact_name","contact_phone"]
    //Getting Cell Value i.e phone number
    array_push($phone_numbers,$row[$col_headers[2]]); //$col_headers[2] is the column index for phone
}
return $phone_numbers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like getting current row number or cell index is not yet implemented in Laravel Excel's exports. See [this](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/issues/2693).

So, for now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202868/how-to-get-number-and-put-header-on-laravel-excel-export)'s a simple workaround for that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).